# Getting StaleElementReferenceException trying one valid and one invalid login

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am trying to write a test for valid and invalid login in same test class but I am getting StaleElementReferenceException. Below is the code

```
public class LoginTest {
    static{
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./driver/chromedriver.exe");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://app.meltwaterbuzz.com/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        LoginPage login = new LoginPage(driver);
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
        login.setUsername("username");
        login.setPassword("password");
        login.clickSignIn();
        login.setUsername("username");
        login.setPassword("password");
        login.clickSignIn();
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

        //driver.close();
    }
}
```

Any idea how to handle this?

Comment: can you tell for which line of code are you getting the exception.

Answer (score 2):

Generally we will be getting the Stale Exception if the element attributes or something is changed after initiating the webelement. For example, in some cases if user tries to click on the same element on the same page but after page refresh, gets staleelement exception.

To overcome this, we can create the fresh webelement in case if the page is changed or refreshed. Below code can give you some idea.

**Example:**

```
webElement element = driver.findElement(by.xpath("//*[@id='StackOverflow']"));
element.click();
//page is refreshed
element.click();//This will obviously throw stale exception
```

To overcome this, we can store the xpath in some string and use it to create a fresh webelement as we go.

```
String xpath = "//*[@id='StackOverflow']";
driver.findElement(by.xpath(xpath)).click();
//page has been refreshed. Now create a new element and work on it
driver.fineElement(by.xpath(xpath)).click();   //This works
```

Hope this helps you. Thanks.

Comment: Yes if we try to find element one more time then definitely it will work but same code is getting repeated multiple time.

Comment: i am not getting you @ZahidAfaque

Comment: You shouldn't take this as code duplication, @santhosh kumar is right. This is a best practice. Loading of all elements at the initialization of the page is maybe reduce the interaction with the dom, but for many reasons, it's not efficient, unless you're messing with a static web page. Dynamic contents are naturally changing after an interaction. 

And adding a manual wait is worst solution as below on your answer. Never do that unless you have to.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

In your code block you are creating an object `login` of  `LoginPage` class, filling up `username`, `password` and you are clicking on `SignIn` button. Once you click on `SignIn` button you are logged in as a registered user and  redirected to a new page. Here the page/url have changed and the HTML DOM have also changed.

Next you are again trying to pass username through `login.setUsername("username")` again and Selenium is unable to find the same locator (id/name/css/xpath) on this new page. Hence Selenium complains of `StaleElementReferenceException` which essentially means the locator you are looking for is no more present on the HTML DOM or have become `stale`.

The solution to your issue would be to `Logout` and come back again to the initial url `http://app.meltwaterbuzz.com/`.

Let me know if this Answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to overcome StaleElementReferenceException, If we use page object model then we can overcome it. Here is the example.

**POM Class**

```
public class LoginPage {
//declaration
@FindBy(id="username")
private WebElement usernameTxt;

@FindBy(name = "pwd")
private WebElement passwordTxt;

@FindBy(css="#loginButton")
private WebElement loginBTN;
//Initialization
public LoginPage(WebDriver driver) {
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
}
//Utilization
public void setUserName(String un) {
    usernameTxt.sendKeys(un);
}

public void setPassword(String pw) {
    passwordTxt.sendKeys(pw);
}

public void clickLogin() {
    loginBTN.click();
}
```

}

**Test Class**

```
public class LoginTest {
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./driver/chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://localhost/login.do");
    LoginPage login = new LoginPage(driver);

    login.setUserName("zahid");
    login.setPassword("manager");
    login.clickLogin();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    login.setUserName("admin");
    login.setPassword("manager");
    login.clickLogin();
}
```

}